# would like someone to meet me

Tags: would

Dear English speaker,

Could you tell me this is correct usages of a sentence in below case?

Case 1:

I'm a beginner or a new in a sector and there is the most famous person in the sector such as a Professor. I would like to meet him. I'm not going to send this inquiry to him. I just want to talk about my thoughts on my blog.

Based on that, Is it correct sentence "I would like him to meet me"?

Please advice me. I'd like to improve my English from Japan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the meeting is in someone’s office. Saying that you would like him to meet you would look like asking him to take the trouble to come to your office. Saying that *you* would like to meet him turns this around, with you visiting him. Unless you have a higher social standing than him, it would sound more reasonable to request to meet him than to request that he meets you.